# Format Code In Directory

Tags: php, format

I took over maintenance of an old PHP system that is in horrible shape. Something that I would like to do is clean up all of the code files and for starters I would like to just format the code so it is easier to work with. Does anybody know of any way to format all of the code files in a directory?

Comment: I usually switch between notepad++ and netbeans. I know both can format the current file that I'm editing, but not a whole directory, and neither seem to do a spectacular job at it.

Answer (score 2):

you should look at [beautifyphp](http://beautifyphp.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

After searching around Google, I found this: [PHP-correct-Indenting](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1120).

**EDIT**: and this too: [PHP Beautifier](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier).